# background processing notification for $http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-service

I am looking for a way to "wrap" all the `$http` requests so that I can show a `gif` image whenever the application is doing some processing. I also want to use the same solution for other kind of background processing and not just `$http`.

The reason why I am asking is that I always have to set my `processingIndicator` to `true` and then switch back in my `success` function which is not elegant at all.

One potentially solution that I see is to use a function that takes a function as a parameter. This function will set the `processingIndicator` to `true`, call the function and then set `processingIndicator` back to `false.

```
function processAjaxRequestSuccessFn(fooFn){
  // display processing indicator
  fooFn();
  // hide processing indicator
}
```

And then

```
$http.get(...).then(processAjaxRequestSuccessFn, processAjaxRequestErrorFn)
```

This solution is not very convenient because every time I need to notify the user that something is happening, I need to use this function.

I am looking for a way to automate this process.

Any other ideas?

**Later edit**

Another idea I have is to extend `$http` with my own `get`, `post`, etc. Or create a custom service that has a similar behavior. But still not very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an interceptor. Observe the following example...

```
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            /*...*/
            return config || $q.when(config);   // -- start request/show gif
        },
        'requestError': function (rejection) {
            /*...*/
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        'response': function (response) {       // -- end request/hide gif
            /*...*/
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            /*...*/
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

---

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
    /*...*/
}]);
```

Here you can inject centralized logic at various points during the http request life cycle, hooking into the supplied callbacks offered by the api. Crafting any reusable request logic you may need - just do so here. Check out the interceptors portion of the [AngularJS $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully managed to use [AngularOverlay](https://github.com/DanWahlin/AngularOverlay) for displaying a loading indicator while a http request is pending. Download the files and follow the instructions and it should work.